# How to retrieve available system ram and battery level

Tags: android, android-memory, batterylevel

Im currently working on an app that I really need help with and I've come to the stage where I need a bit of help. Ok so I am trying to get the amount of free system memory/Ram and the battery level of the device and I want to display them in my app activity.

here is what I have so far.

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
```

Comment: will somebody please help me?

Comment: ok didnt work and also it didnt tell me how to dislpay it as a text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register for this action in your activity Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

And write below code to get battery level from the broadcast receiver.

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        } 
    }
};
```

level  value gives the battery level of your device.